# Group Isomorphic problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

> Prove that for any groups, $G$ and $H$, we have $$(G \times H)/G' ≅ H\tag{1}$$ and $$(G \times H)/H' ≅ G,\tag{2}$$ where $G' =\{(g,e) \in G \times H | g \in G\}$ and $H' =\{(e,h) \in G \times H | h \in H\}$.

I tried to first expand this by plugging the identities in but I couldn't find anything to go off of. Is there some simple thing I'm missing?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

First make sure you understand why $G'$ and $H'$ are normal subgroups.

We will demonstrate a very simple example of the first isomorphism theorem. Namely:

Define $\pi: G \times H \to H$ by $\pi(g,h) = h$. It is clear that $\pi$ is surjective, and make sure you understand why it is a homomorphism of groups.

Now what is its kernel? It is the set $\{(g,h) \in G \times H : h = e\}$ which is $G'$.

The first isomorphism theorem then gives $(G \times H) / G' \cong H$ (and the other claim is symmetric, now).

Now in case you haven't yet learned the isomorphism theorems we can do:

1. Show $G'$ is normal in the product $G \times H$. Hence $(G \times H) / G'$ has the structure of a group.
2. Note that $(g_1, h_1)G' = (g_2, h_2)G'$ if and only if $(g_1 g_2^{-1}, h_1 h_2^{-1}) \in G'$, or $h_1 = h_2$, simply.

This implies we can define a group homomorphism:

3. Define $\psi:(G \times H) / G' \to H$ by $\psi((g,h)G') = h$. To make the point clear, this assignment is well defined because $(g_1,h_1)G' = (g_2,h_2)G'$ if and only if $h_1 = h_2$. Now show this function is a homomorphism, surjective and injective. Let's show injectivity, for example:

$h = e_H$ implies that for any $g \in G$, $(g,h)G' = (g, e_H)G' = G'$.

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: How would I show surjectivity? Thank you!

Comment: @JamesDone Given $h \in H$, what pair in $G \times H$ can you pick that will map to $h$?

Comment: is it the element $g$?

Comment: @JamesDone no, what is the domain of the map we've defined? How can it be $g$?

Comment: The domain is $(g,h)G'$

Comment: @JamesDone sure elements of this form. Strictly speaking the domain is $G \times H / G'$. Now which element here maps to $h$ under $\psi$?

Comment: Is it just $(g,h)$?

Comment: @JamesDone an element $(g,h)G'$ will do. Do you understand why $(g,h)G' = (e,h)G'$, for instance?